# Read the contents of a folder with files/sub folders with javascript/html5/angularjs/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I want to read files and sub folders under a folder selected through `<input type="file">`

I am aware of the fact that I could use `<input type="file" multiple webkitdirectory />`. Since this solution is chrome specific I cannot use it.

I have searched extensively online but did not find a solution that would work on all browsers to read the files/sub folders of a selected folder using javascript,html5, angularjs or jquery.

Please advise how to achieve this functionality.

Comment: There is no way to do this in non-webkit browsers, unless you use a browser plugin like Flash.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is useful, but I've used [ElFinder.NET](http://www.leniel.net/2013/04/manage-folders-and-files-in-your-aspnet-mvc-project-with-elfinder-net-file-manager.html#sthash.FqKwa0aC.dpbs) with angularjs/javascript/ASP.NET/C#  But you might find something similar to this implementation

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41770366/188963):

FileSystem API is currently being supported only on Chrome and Opera 
http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem

Also you need to obtain permissions from the user to access peristent data.

For more info refer to this article : 
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#Reading a directory's contents