# How to get local folder contents using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, image, file

I am trying to get local folder contents using JavaScript. I have tried the Filesystem API, but I got error like this:

**DOMException: It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources**

How can I get images in a local folder and show these images as HTML? Folder structure and images inside a folder are changing dynamically.

Edit: I tried the filesystem here: https://github.com/maciel310/angular-filesystem

Comment: Is the page being served locally? Are you asking the end user to drag a folder into the page, or are you trying to access the contents of their hard drive without their intervention?

Comment: By "being served locally," I mean you are accessing it from a `file:` URI, not from `http://localhost`.

Comment: I tried both file:URI and http://localhost, but I got the same error.

Comment: What about the second half of the question? Is the user dragging a folder into your web application? If not, do you understand why it's a grave security problem to allow web applications unfettered access to a user's local disks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FileSystem API is currently being supported only on Chrome and Opera 
http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem

Also you need to obtain permissions from the user to access peristent data.

For more info refer to this article : 
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#Reading a directory's contents

Comment: But before this is standardized, don't use it.